# Showing a language is context free. Use PDA or CFG?

Tags: computability, context-free, automata, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

I am wondering on how to approach a specific problem I am struggling with. I am not understanding which way to approach it and how to solve it.

Show language $L$ is context free, where $L = \{\text{all strings where middle two symbols are the same}\}$

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, it's easier to come up with a CFG than it is to invent a PDA. First, notice that the strings should all be of even length, otherwise it's not clear what "middle two symbols" should mean. Here are some hints to get you going.

**Hint 1**. Could you have grammar rules $T\rightarrow (something)$ which would generate all strings $xx$, where $x$ is a symbol from your alphabet?

**Hint 2**. If you had a start variable $S$, could you make productions of the form $S\rightarrow (symbol_1)\; S\; (symbol_2)$ that would generate all sentential forms $\alpha\;S\;\beta$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be any strings over your alphabet and have the same length?

If you can do these two tasks, the CFG is easy.